# I have calendar functionality but for one date it's jumping to next year, supposed to go to next month

Tags: javascript

This is is my js code

when I click on next month its going to next year

```js
function quickNavMonth(direction) {
 var gotodate = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', getDatebyLocale($("#wkEndDate").html()));
 var fiscalMonthIndex = parseInt($("#fiscalMonthOfYear").html(), 10)-1;
 //Set the gotoDate as the 15th of every month for it to pickup the right fiscal calendar month.
 gotodate.setDate(15);
 gotodate.setMonth(fiscalMonthIndex + parseInt(direction));
 // Fiscal Calender issue
 if(isDateOutsideFiscalCalendar(gotodate)) {
  openAlertDialog(getTextTranslation("FISCAL_CAL_UNAVAIL_DATE"), getTextTranslation("ERR_MSG_TITLE_UNAVAILABLE_FISCAL_CAL"));
 } else {
  var dteStr = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', gotodate);
  var newURL = 
  changeLocation(changeParam("weekEnding", dteStr));
 }
}
```

Comment: so what are the values of the variables in this state?

Comment: gotodate is current date, fiscalMonthIndex is 0 and direction can be either 1,0 or -1